# Replace all src/href references to include a site root directory in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose i have loaded some html data from ajax.
The ajax returned an an html form.
The issue arises when loading the resources in the loaded data. Let me elaborate..

For example, the ajax may receive a script tag referenced to "`/script.js`". But since my page would be on (let's say) a separate domain the browser wouldn't recognize the url "/script.js". So what I'm looking to do is replace all of the links like "`/abc.xy`" to be linking to the domain form which i'd be loading the resource originally..

So, all references like "`/abc.xy`" would be changed to **"`www.domain.com/abc.xy`"**

How would i achieve this? *(if it is even possible)*

Answer (score 0):

```
function resolve(old,new){
  [...document.getElementsByClassName("*")].forEach(el=>{
     if(el.src){
       el.src=el.src.replace(old,new);
     }
     if(el.href){
       el.href=el.href.replace(old,new);
     }
});
}
```

Use like this:

```
resolve("http://original.com/","http://new.com/");
```